# Generating random number based on chance

Tags: elixir

Welcome to casino ;)

I have a "possible win" number, for example 33.3.

Win chance = 33%, so ~every 3rd roll should win in this case.

Another example: number 1 should win with 1/100 chance.

How can i implement it using elixir, how to create correct rand func to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Erlang's [`random`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/random.html) module:

```
:random.uniform()
```

which will generate a float between 0.0 and 1.0. Anything below `1/3` is a "win", anything above that is a "loss".

Answer (score 1):

Create list with 100 elements.
Take 1 random element from this list.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7, ... , 100]
Enum.take_random(list, 1)
```

or

```
Enum.take_random(1..100,1)
```

or

```
Enum.take_random(1..100)
```

33% - wins if taken random element is < 34.

1/100 - wins if taken random element is 1.

etc.

Works from Elixir 1.1 up.